# why I should use await?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, c#-5.0

I am new to async / await. but I created the POC but I am still confused.

Outcome of method

```
public async void WriteLineFunc(string str)
    {
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => WaitFor2Secs());
        //WaitFor2Secs();
        Console.WriteLine(str);
    }
```

and

```
public async void WriteLineFunc(string str)
    {
        //await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => WaitFor2Secs());
        WaitFor2Secs();
        Console.WriteLine(str);
    }
```

is same. What is point of making a method as await? Just to run a function on other thread and wait for its completion?

Comment: The first version allows the main thread to do other things while waiting. The second version does not let the thread do anything during the wait. Allowing the main thread to do other things means that the application remains responsive.

Comment: you mean statement `await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => WaitFor2Secs());` is equal to `Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => WaitFor2Secs());
             Task.WaitAll(t);`

Comment: No. `WaitAll` holds the thread hostage while it waits.

Comment: what do you mean by thread hostage? do you mean that the same thread can do some other thing even if it is waiting?

Comment: @D J: Yes.  Try putting this code in a simple windows forms or wpf project instead. You'll discover that the thread which is responsible for pumping messages can continue to pump messages and maintain a responsive ui in your first example. In your second example (assuming WaitFor2Secs is a sleep), you'll block the UI thread and make your user interface non-responsive for the duration of the wait.

Comment: thats great explanation.. +1 pls put that as answer i want to accept it..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When a method uses `await`, it can return to its caller before it's complete.

Consider this example:

```
public async Task WriteLineFuncAsync(string str)
{
  await Task.Delay(2000);
  Console.WriteLine(str);
}

public void WriteLineFunc(string str)
{
  Thread.Sleep(2000);
  Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```

`WriteLineFunc` will synchronously block the running thread for 2 seconds and then write out the string. `WriteLineFuncAsync` will immediately return an incomplete `Task` to its caller; two seconds later, it will write out the string and then complete the `Task`.

For client-side applications, the main benefit is *responsiveness* (the GUI thread is not blocked). For server-side applications, the main benefit is *scalability* (you can have far more responses than threads).

Comment: actually I need to know the concept behind the await. I know that it helps us to run the things on background and await. But your async method is same as `public void WriteLineFuncAsync(string str)
        {
            Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Task.Delay(2000));
            Task.WaitAll(t);
            Console.WriteLine(str);
        }`

Comment: @DJ No, it's not. For one, your method won't actually wait. `Task.Delay()` doesn't block a thread while waiting, it just returns a `Task` that will complete after a given time.

Comment: @DJ: You may find my [async/await intro](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) helpful.